# Effect on views , synonyms and indexes by dropping a table

Tags: oracle, indexing, view, synonym

I want to know the output effect of dropping a table . what happens to the associated views , synonyms and indexes after dropping the table .

Comment: Did you post this question so you could also answer it? If so you should post your response **as an actual answer** instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping a table removes the table definition from the data dictionary. All rows of the table are no longer accessible and have moved to recycle bin .

All views dependent on a dropped table remain, yet become invalid (not usable).

All synonyms for a dropped table remain, but return an error when used.

All indexes and triggers associated with a table are dropped.

Actually views and synonyms depends on the table and indexes and triggers belongs to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a table invalidates objects which have a dependency on the table: those views, synonyms and procedures are not dropped but cannot be used until we intervene to make them compile (e.g. by editing the source code).

Objects which actually belong to the table - triggers, indexes and constraints - are dropped along with the table.